# Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*По последним данным, события  олимпиады будут разворачиваться в Лондоне.*

Правда же, что между словами *данным* и *события* нужна запятая? Надеюсь, поможете мне выиграть спор. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, "запЯтая". Во-вторых, "данными" и "события" берутся в кавычки. В-третьих, после "надеюсь" ставится запятая. В-четвертых, сама фраза, которую Вы приводите, тоже берется в кавычки. В-пятых, во втором предложении в конце вопросительный знак.
Ну, а в остальном Вы правы, запятая тут действительно нужна.

Comment: Спасибо большое!